# Apache FOP: Charts and Diagrammes in PDF?

Tags: xml, pdf, xsl-fo, apache-fop

i'm using FOP for our reporting tools, thanks to FOP we can make a nice
 looking PDF-File.

I need to generate not only tables or text, but also some
 charts/diagramms ( like pie chart, gantt , etc)
 and this charts should be embeded in the pdf, as a graphic format (
 like SVG or JPEG )
 Does anyone have any idea how to do these things ? somekind of library
 maybe ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With FO rendering, you'd have basically two routes to choose from. Your charts and diagrams could be external files that you would refer to in the FO markup with fo:external-graphic. Or you could try embedding them with fo:instream-foreign-object. This works for SVG, but I'm not sure if its a good option for other formats.

As for creating the contents of those charts and diagrams, that is a whole other issue.